# HBase setting timestamp

Tags: java, api, hadoop, hbase

I'm having problems setting row timestamp using java api.

When I'm trying to add a timestamp value to put constructor (or into put.add()) nothing happens and after reading rows from table I get system provided timestamps.

```
public static boolean addRecord(String tableName, String rowKey,
    String family, String qualifier, Object value)
{
    try {
        HTable table = new HTable(conf, tableName);
        Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey), 12345678l);
        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(family), Bytes.toBytes(qualifier), Bytes.toBytes(value.toString()));
        table.put(put);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

HBase 0.92.1 running in standalone mode.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you provide more information? What version of HBase are you using? Are there concurrent writes to that row? It might be that version 12345678L gets successfully stored, but you have system provided timestamps that are newer than 12345678L. Try getting all versions of that row and checking whether 12345678L is there.

Comment: HBase 0.92.1. There is only one version of that row (I've set max versions number in get and checked).

Comment: Could you paste the output of "hbase> describe 't1'" (HBase Shell) for your table t1 (whatever name it has)? This will give us information about the column families you are trying to write to. There might be issues such as Time To Live for the families. Also try writing to an empty row, you should definitely get the timestamp you want, since there should be no other version.

Comment: {NAME => 'TestTableName', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'Family1', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '3', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => '2147483647', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 'Family2', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLIC                            
 ATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '3', COMPRESSION =>'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => '2147483647', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}]}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely, you already have rows in the table that have timestamp > `12345678l`. To confirm that this is not the case, try it with a very large value for timestamp, say `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

If it is indeed the case, you can simply delete the older versions. Then this entry will show up.

Comment: In official hbase book http://hbase.apache.org/book/versions.html 
it is said 
"Doing a put always creates a new version of a cell, at a certain timestamp. By default the system uses the server's currentTimeMillis, but you can specify the version (= the long integer) yourself, on a per-column level. This means you could assign a time in the past or the future, or use the long value for non-time purposes."

Comment: Yes, but the version with maximum timestamp will be shown if you use get(),  unless you use setMaxVersions() to get the 'older' (i.e, with lower timestamp) versions. So if there already exist the same cell with timestamp > 12345678, then that one will be shown.

Comment: I've already tried setting max versions number to 10 - there is only one version of this row.

Comment: What is the timestamp of the version that you get?

Comment: And how are you "getting" the row? Is through the Java API or through HBase Shell? In HBase Shell you should specify many versions, like "hbase> get 't1', 'r1', {VERSIONS => 100}". In the Java API, the Result object from HTable.get(Get) has two methods: getColumnLatest and getColumn. The latter is a list of versions.

Comment: Raze2dust, I'm getting a system time when the record was added.
STALTZ, I'm getting through java api using result scanner.

Comment: At last I've found it! You all were right - the record was overwritten with later timestamp - I saw it in shell using TIMERANGE. To get the valid timestamp I need to add it not only in Put constructor, but also in every add() call. Thank You very much!